# java manifest internal jar link

Tags: java, jar, manifest

I'm trying to package some external libraries into my java project, but failing miserably. I've got a .jar-file, with external libraries packaged into ./lib/jars. If I have the manifest pointing the Class-Path: at lib/jars/theJar.jar, I get a NoClassDefFoundError. If I have the Class-Path pointing at C:\Users\Owner\workspace\theProject\lib\jars\theJar.jar, the jar file is found - but I suppose that will only work on my computer.

How do I make the program go looking for the jars inside of the jar?

Answer (score 0):

You don't, unless you use a custom classloader like [JarClassLoader](http://www.jdotsoft.com/JarClassLoader.php).

Alternatives include things like [jarjar](http://code.google.com/p/jarjar/) and [One-JAR](http://one-jar.sourceforge.net/).

*Edit* It appears I misunderstood your problem, based on your question title--they're not really "internal", they're external, as your question correctly states. The last sentence is again misleading: are you trying to reference external jars, or jars inside of the jar?